# How can an add-in add a NavigationModule in Outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook

How can I a NavigationModule to the Outlook 2007 Navigation Pane? I'd like to do it through the API but other solutions are good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done through the OOM, you really only have Form regions which I guess may not fit the bill.

It could be done through Subclassing and Hooking resize events at a win api level.